# The first step in finding the right site

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I have a question that could be placed in a number of places within SE but none of them are a good fit.

It's about hosting of my self-generated map tiles but all the answers ( questions on SO ) tend to point to OSM or OpenMapTiles. All roads on web searching lead to places like those but they have the (wrong) assumption that I want to use their Saas or BaaS.

Ultimately it's a coding question for a mobile app which suggests SO as the place, but in order to post the right question there, I need to do more learning.

My question here is, where do I bare my limited understanding in order to start a productive Q & A trail

Comment: Thumbs up for doing research on the most fitting site before posting a question! Unfortunately I can't help you find the correct place for your question. Normally I would suggest reading the off/on topic help on SE sites, but it sounds like you already did that.

Comment: Can you post the actual question title you want to ask?

Comment: @Patrick - if only i could ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any questions about geospatial programming I think that you should consider the [GIS Stack Exchange](https://gis.stackexchange.com):

> **Geographic Information Systems** is a question and answer site for people interested in **GIS**, **Remote Sensing**, **Photogrammetry**,
>   **Geodesy** and **Surveying**, *as well as Programming/Databases specific to the aforementioned*.

If you decide to ask there be sure to review [Asking good Questions for GIS Stack Exchange?](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3349/asking-good-questions-for-gis-stack-exchange) first.

Answer (score 3):

> I have a question that could be placed in a number of places within SE but none of them are a good fit.
>
> ...
>
> My question here is, where do I bare my limited understanding in order to start a productive Q & A trail

With the 4 upvotes on this question, you have the 20 rep necessary to participate in chat. Site chatrooms are reasonable places to raise questions which aren't great fits for the main site but are close enough that the site's community might have useful ideas. They're also better suited than the main site to a "trail" of questions.

I would suggest looking at the chat rooms of the sites which are more-or-less relevant, and trying to pick one which is not so inactive that no-one will see the question but not so active that it will be off the page in 5 minutes. Then outline your question and ask whether people think it's on topic for the site, if not whether there is another site that they participate in<sup>1</sup> where it would be on topic, and failing that whether anyone is willing to discuss it with you in a spin-off chatroom.

---

<sup>1</sup> This is important. It's far too frequent that someone will say "This question doesn't belong here, but it belongs on stack XYZ" despite never participating in XYZ and not knowing what the XYZ community considers on-topic. This kind of advice leads to frustration for the OP and the XYZ community, but unfortunately has no negative consequences for the person making the bad recommendation.

Comment: your footnote nailed it. I marked Polygeo as the more faithful answer, but your  context of the finer points of chat rooms are extremely valuable, and to those in the future who have this same question